# Can Hostelworld Gold membership numbers be shared among multiple accounts?

Tags: online-resources, loyalty-programs, hostels, hostelworld

Is a [Hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com) Gold membership locked to one particular account, or can it be used when make booking from separate accounts to get a discount? If the latter, then does Hostelworld invalidate cards that are shared by 'too many' accounts?

Comment: A question that could be answered easily by someone who has a gold card (I keep getting free ones through promotions they run), but don't want to have my card invalidated trying to test this. :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a Hostelworld membership, but I emailed them to see what the official stance is (without anyone risking getting their card invalidated).

From Louise Clark on the customer service team:

> Thanks for your email.  Gold Cards are registered to one email address so all bookings made with that address will be automatically discounted.
>   You can also enter the Gold Card number when using a different email address and the discount will still apply.
>   This is not limited to a certain number of email addresses.

So it looks like the answer is: enter in the membership number on as many bookings as you'd like from as many email addresses you'd like. :) Happy traveling!

Comment: awesome! I'd tweeted them but without response.  So @Ankur...care to share your gold card number then? ;)