# How do I get a free Hostelworld Gold card?

Tags: online-resources, loyalty-programs, hostels, hostelworld

I heard that [Hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com) gives out regularly free Gold Cards. But how can I get such a card? I couldn't find anything one [their homepage](http://www.hostelworld.com/supportcentre.php).

Comment: Also see [Can Hostelworld Gold memberships be shared among multiple accounts?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/700/108)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[HostelWorld Gold Cards](http://www.hostelworld.com/goldcard/) can be bought for $10 whenever you're making a booking. This waives the $2 booking fee that HostelWorld charges. (It will not, however, waive the 10% downpayment.) There are a couple of ways to get it for free though.

- [Follow @hostelworld on Twitter](http://twitter.com/hostelworld). Every now and then, they send out Gold Card codes to new followers. I got one that was valid for six months!
- Sign up for [a HostelWorld MyWorld account](http://www.hostelworld.com/myworld) and make all your booking through it. Per night, per person you get 10 loyalty points on a booking. You also get 20 points for reviewing a hostel, and another 20 points for reviewing the city you stayed in. Now, the [MyWorld Points page](http://www.hostelworld.com/myworld/points/) (n.b. you need to be logged in) says you need 1000 points to get a Gold Membership, but I get a goody bag instead whenever I hit 500 points which - surprise, surprise - *also* contains a Gold Card! If you travel around a fair bit and make most of your bookings through HostelWorld, 500 points is an easy target to hit.

Not related to the Gold Card, but every now and then HostelWorld runs contests on its homepage. Most of these contests are simple questionnaires for the purpose of signing you up for their newsletter. And in many of these contests, they offer no booking fees ($2 charge + downpayment waived). Keep a lookout for these too.

Comment: Of course you could always just book through [HostelBookers](http://www.hostelbookers.com/) instead of HostelWorld, since they don't have a booking fee in the first place.

Comment: @ankur what is in the goody bag. I am about to hit 500 points, and need to decide whether to take it or save more

Comment: @Midhat Eyeshade, keychain with bottle opener, maps of every continent with overview of places to visit. And sometimes they throw in a Gold Card too but this is variable.